# Not receiving a tax refund because local taxes weren't withheld on my paycheck?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, calculation, state-income-tax, income-tax-refund

For instance, if the local New York City tax wasn't taken out of my paycheck, does that directly affect my tax refund?

From what I understand the calculation for a tax refund is dependent on whether or not money was taken out of your paycheck. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

The IRS can direct your refund towards repayment of your unpaid taxes either on Federal or State/Local level. Whether it will depends on whether the State of New York will ask for it.

Generally, if you owe taxes to New York for this year only, you would expect them to wait for you to file your State tax return and pay the taxes owed. If you don't - I'm pretty sure that the next year refund from the IRS will go directly to them.

Answer (score 1):

As a resident of New York State you will, in addition to the Federal income tax handled by the IRS, be responsible for state and local income taxes.

For New York the state tax forms are also used to determine your New York city tax. If HR was either not aware of the local tax requirement for New York or you filled out the [New York State version of the W-4](http://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/wt/it2104_fill_in.pdf) incorrectly you may have had too little tax withheld for New York state.

The refund from the IRS is not dependent on the refund/owe status for state and local taxes. It is possible that your state taxes are fine but that you owe taxes to the city. That tax you owe to the city will reduce the refund from the state and may require you to pay money to New York.

Of course if you do itemize, what you pay to the state and city may result in deductions on your federal form. If you owe back taxes to the state or local government this could result in the IRS seizing a federal refund, but that doesn't happen right away.